# How to remove first row in every grouped result ordered on date column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a sql data (table) which consists of `n` number of columns, but 3 are of particular interest

| claim_id | patient_id | admission_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p_1 | 2001-01-01 |
| 2 | p_2 | 2001-02-01 |
| 3 | p_1 | 2001-01-01 |
| 4 | p_3 | 2001-02-02 |
| 5 | p_2 | 2001-03-01 |
| 6 | p_2 | 2001-04-01 |
| 7 | p_1 | 2001-04-01 |

What I want is remove first row (based on `admission_date`) of every `patient_id`.  In case there are two rows for any patient on his/her first date of admission (e.g. `patient_id = p_1` having 2 rows `1 & 3` with same dates of admission) then remove all those rows; and get an output like this

| claim_id | patient_id | admission_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | p_2 | 2001-03-01 |
| 6 | p_2 | 2001-04-01 |
| 7 | p_1 | 2001-04-01 |

I am not very well conversant with sql, but I can do that easily in `R` using `duplicated`.  Is something like that, a memory efficient (I have to filter 10 million rows at least) is available in POSTGRESQL?

What I have tried?  Basically nothing in sql.  If that data was of less size I could have exported it in R and have done my analysis there.

Please help.

Comment: Claim_id is a primary key? {patient_id,admission_date} is a unique?

Comment: Yes @wildplasser, claim_id is unique identifier key in this transaction table.  `patient_id` + `admission_date` combination may not be unique, but if that is the condition, we can safely exclude all rows falling on first date of admission of that patient_id

Comment: If there happens to be only one record for a patient_id: do you want to suppress that, too?

Comment: yes like `patient_id` `p_3` has only 1 claim and I don't want that in output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for that:

```
select claim_id, patient_id, admission_date
from (
  select claim_id, patient_id, admission_date, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by patient_id order by admission_date) as rn
   from the_table
) t 
where rn > 1;
```

`dense_rank()` creates sequential numbers for each patient_id sorted by the admission_date. If two rows have the same admission_date, they will get the same "rank". The WHERE clause in the outer query simply removes the "first" row for each patient.

Answer (score 1):

We can use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT claim_id, patient_id, admission_date
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.patient_id = t1.patient_id AND
                    t2.claim_id < t1.claim_id);
```

Given that some patients seems to have mutilple admissions on the same date, I am using the `claim_id` as an ordered identifier to determine what admission came first.

If performance of the above be a concern, then the following index should speed things up substantially:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (patient_id, claim_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have seen that these join type of queries take days in my actual data to process

Comment: @AnilGoyal Then add an index per my suggestion.  My query can be made performant if tuned properly, I believe.

Comment: Creating indices will certainly enhance the performance.  But not everytime index creation rights are given to analysts.  In my case index creation rights are not given.

Comment: But still I am trying to do the filtering on both methods suggested.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: @AnilGoyal : in that case, the data model should contain a PG on claim_id and an addtitional index (Non unique?) on {patient_id,admission_date} [see my first comment]

Comment: This solution was also great.  Accepting other one as that served my purpose well.